# Symfony2 best way to store user data?

Tags: php, symfony, session

We are in the middle of migrating our web app from using Symfony 1.4 to Symfony 2.5. One issue I've run across is that the user class does not have a getAttribute os setAttribute method anymore:

```
$user->getAttribute('regions', array(), 'sfGuardSecurityUser');
```

This has been deprecated. What would be the best object/method to use to replace this functionality. I've thought about using the session to store the variables (mostly ids), but I've read that's a bad idea. I'm also using the FriendsOfSymfony bundle and my User class extends the base class.

Comment: What ids do you mean? If it should be your internal entities' ids, than it will be better to create direct relations from your extended user class to those entities.

Comment: @RomaKliuchko it's table ids to the user's locations/customizations. The code we are trying to convert into Symfony2 uses these ids frequently. It's a data centric website.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the getAttribute and setAttribute methods of symfony 1.4 only store the values to the session so the Symfony 2 equivilent should be:

```
$session = $this->container->get('session');

$session->set('name', 'Drak');
$session->get('name');
```

see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html